# Copying table contents to another with loops

Tags: c#, loops

I'm fresh to C# and I've got a homework problem I'm struggling with. I can't copy the contents of a table to another one with loops. I want it to copy positive numerals from a 10-element predefined table to the second and show the contents in the console after it's done.

```
int[] tab1 = { 4, 6, 32, 16, 5, 22, -3, 61, 11, 99 };
int[] tab2 = new int[tab1.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < tab2.Length; i++)
{
  while(i > 0)
  {
    tab2[i] = tab1[i];
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < tab2.Length; i++)
{
  Console.Write(tab2[i] + ", ");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Take a look at `while(i > 0)`.  Has `i` already been set to something else?

Comment: seems like you want `if(tab1[i] > 0)` to check if the value at that position is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item that is positive puts your program into an infinite loop.

Change `while` inside the `for` loop to an `if`. Inside the `while` you have `tab2[i] = tab1[i];`, which, for each `i`, will never change the condition on the while loop. So for each item in the array you will either execute the assignment for an item ad infinitum  or never execute the assignment.

Changing `while` to `if` removes the loop (in the loop) and evaluates the conditional expression for the *single element in the loop*.

Another way to think of this is this: "for each of these items, if that item is positive I will assign it to the other array". What you expressed, in code, was "for each of these items, while that item is positive, assign it to the other array", which doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many items positive(will be in the tab2), you cannot define the size of the second array. So you better to use **List**, where you can store the required number of items. **if (tab1[i] > 0)** will examine the item in the first array.

```
int[] tab1 = { 4, 6, 32, 16, 5, 22, -3, 61, 11, 99 };
List<int> tab2 = new List<int>();// because you dont know how many items positive
for (int i = 0; i < tab1.Length; i++)
{
    if (tab1[i] > 0)
    {
      tab2.Add(tab1[i]);
     }
  }

 for (int i = 0; i < tab2.Count; i++)
 {
   Console.Write(tab2[i] + ", ");
 }
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.